# grunt/compass exclude files from compiling

Tags: magento, sass, gruntjs, compass

I'm currently developing a magento theme. I'm using grunt-compass and grunt-watch to compile my scss files. I would like to speed up the process with excluding styles-IE8.scss for compiling (because it's not used in developing environment).

I could (of course) rename to _styles-IE8.scss and rename it back for production, but isn't there a better way to define which files to compile and which not?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `grunt-contrib-compass`, in your Gruntfile.js you can use the [`specify`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#specify) option to exclude files.

> Lets you specify which files you want to compile. Useful if you don't want to compile the whole folder. Globbing supported. Ignores filenames starting with underscore. Paths are relative to the Gruntfile.

ex:

```
compass: {
    options: {
        specify: "!/path/to/styles-IE8.scss"
    }
}
```

Then, depending on the environment you can set `specify` dynamically.